# Play MP4 while recording moov atom.

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, vlc

I am recording a video with VLC using MP4 Encapsulation + h264 codec. The video is recorded correctly , but I need to be able to access and play the recorded video while recording from a winform c# application.

I have integrated VLC in the winform application but the problem is that the mp4 file is not playable during recording.

I understood that the problem is the moov atom file is created at the end when the recording as terminated.

First solution I have found is to copy the file when the user need to access the file then generate a moov atom using for example MP4Box utility.

Does anybody know a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post all caps titles (or all caps anything).